# How to do edits and check in using python in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio-2010, automated-tests

Open Visual Studio -> Go To Projects -> ABC Folder -> abc.txt

Open abc.txt, append a row of data and check-in

I need to do it through python using a Tkinter Gui.

How do I connect?

Comment: connect? what do you mean by connect?

Comment: @CoolCloud by connect I mean to have one access to Visual Studio project I am using

Comment: i actually dont understand what your trying to do here? Make a gui with python? I think you want to make a program the opens a txt file and writes data to it but with a gui

Comment: @CoolCloud I have my gui . I need a way to connect to my Visual Studio 2015 and edit some files and check-in those files with python logic .

Comment: i actually dont think the connection part is possible, but you can edit some files and all with python logic